# use AdaptiveAvgPool2d for CNN in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I try to train a CNN with different size images but it throws an error
`ValueError: expected sequence of length 1200 at dim 2 (got 1069)`
when I convert them to tensor.

I think it is because of the different size images. But I don't want to resize the images. How can I use AdaptiveAvgPool2d?

Here is my code:

```
def makeData():
    data = []
    # cat
    for i in range(1, 11):
        data.append({"path": "images/cat_" + str(i) + ".jpeg", "label": 1})
    # not cat
    for i in range(1, 11):
        data.append({"path": "images/not_cat_" + str(i) + ".jpeg", "label": 0})
    return data

def loadImage(path):
    return Image.open(path).convert('RGB')

class MyDataset(Data.Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.transform = transforms.Compose([
            transforms.ToTensor(),
            transforms.Normalize(mean=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5), std=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5))  
        ])
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        img = loadImage(self.data[idx]["path"])
        img = self.transform(img)
        label = torch.FloatTensor([self.data[idx]["label"]])
        return img, torch.FloatTensor(label)

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.data)
    
def collate_fn(batch_list):
    data, labels = [], []
    for item in batch_list:
        data.append(item[0].tolist())
        labels.append(item[1].tolist())
    return torch.FloatTensor(data), torch.FloatTensor(labels)


loader = Data.DataLoader(MyDataset(makeData()), 2, True, collate_fn=collate_fn)
```

And here is my code of the model:

```
class CatModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 32, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding=1)
        self.act1 = nn.ReLU()
        self.drop1 = nn.Dropout(0.3)
 
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(32, 32, kernel_size=(3,3), stride=1, padding=1)
        self.act2 = nn.ReLU()
        self.pool2 = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d((16, 16))
 
        self.flat = nn.Flatten()
 
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(8192, 512)
        self.act3 = nn.ReLU()
        self.drop3 = nn.Dropout(0.5)
 
        self.fc4 = nn.Linear(512, 1)
 
    def forward(self, x):
        # input 3x32x32, output 32x32x32
        x = self.act1(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.drop1(x)
        # input 32x32x32, output 32x32x32
        x = self.act2(self.conv2(x))
        # input 32x32x32, output 32x16x16
        x = self.pool2(x)
        # input 32x16x16, output 8192
        x = self.flat(x)
        # input 8192, output 512
        x = self.act3(self.fc3(x))
        x = self.drop3(x)
        # input 512, output 1
        x = self.fc4(x)
        return nn.Sigmoid()(x)
```

I added AdaptiveAvgPool2d layers and few dropout and linear layers.

Comment: Where is the code of your model?

Answer (score 4):

The error is caused by trying to batch images of different sizes together. You need to add a resize transformation to your `transforms.Compose`  block prior to `transforms.ToTensor()` to make all the input images the same size. If you check the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/transforms.html) there's a couple ways to do it.

wrt `AdaptiveAvgPool2d`, that serves a different purpose. Older CNNs that used max pooling with a fixed window size could only process a specific input size, say a 224x224 image. If you used a different input image size, your pooled output would be either too large or too small for the linear layers after the CNN encoder. `AdaptiveAvgPool2d` pools a tensor to a specific desired output size. This allows the encoder to process any input image size and still have the right pooled size for the final linear layers.

Comment: But Why I have to resize the image if I used AdaptiveAvgPool2d? Because I want to use a different input image size.

Comment: You can use any image size, but all images within a batch must be the same size. You cannot batch tensors of different size. The error is because you are trying to batch together image tensors that are not the same size.

Comment: I'm confused. If I have to resize the images within a batch. Why I have to use AdaptiveAvgPool2d for a different input image size? Because if I resize the images within a batch, it means the size of images is not different

Comment: You can pass a batch of any size, but all images within a batch must be the same size. You can't batch different sized tensors.

Comment: Why the AdaptiveAvgPool2d is used for this? all images are already same size in a batch.

Comment: If you use standard pooling, your input must be a specific size determined by the model architecture. If you use adaptive pooling, you can use any input size. In both cases, all items in a batch must be the same size. If that's too complicated for you to understand, I can't help you.